# incremental load in datawarehouse

Tags: talend, data-warehouse

I have two tables ( Tparam & Customer ) in talend. The first table contains the global UPDATE date of the database and the table Customer contains many rows and every row has a column named `UPDATE DATE`.

Now I need to have incremental loading in the database with this talend job. I should get the rows where `UPDATE DATE > GLOBAL  UPDATE DATE` and load them in the datawarehouse.

I tried to put global update date in a variable and run a job to select the rows where update date > GLOBAL UPDATE DATE.

Below is my job :  in the tjavaFlex i have created a string which contains the query and the variable global update variable.
the query is:

```
String Query = "SELECT *  FROM [ProjetBI_DW].[dbo].[W_CLIENT_D] where [UPDATE_DATE]";
```

and in the body:

```
Query = Query + ">" + row5.UPDATEDATE ;
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJvaz.png]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use

```
Query + ">" + row5.UPDATEDATE ;
```

As row5 is you current flow, it won't work to use it in tMSSQLInput_5 component. You should use a global or context variable.

In your first subjob, you should put your update date in a global variable, or in a context variable.

The query in your "tParam" component should return only one row , " globalUpdateDate".
Then you can use a simple tJavaRow instead of tJavaFlex with code :

```
context.myGlobalUpdateDate = input_row.globalUpdateDate
```

Don't forget to declare your context variable in the job.

Then in tMSSSQLInput_5 , use the query with your context variable.

```
"SELECT *  FROM [ProjetBI_DW].[dbo].[W_CLIENT_D] where [UPDATE_DATE] > '"+context.myGlobalUpdateDate+"'"
```